# How to make SCSS changes to images on rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using ruby on rails and bootstrap for a nav-bar - want to set up a way of changing the 'ZM logo' size through an scss stylesheet setup to alter the nav bar.

Application.html.erb =

```
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <%= link_to image_tag('ZM Logo (colour).jpg'), class: "Logo" %> 
    </a>
  </div>


    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Home", root_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "About", about_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Contact", "#", class: "nav-link" %></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In stylesheets I have created a navbar.scss file to make the changes in and have added an @import for that file in applications.  Class 'Logo' just doesn't seem to be working.

Any thoughts would be brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

When you write the code like this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('ZM Logo (colour).jpg'), class: "Logo" %>
```

You are applying the class `"Logo"` to the `a` tag.

When you write the code like this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('ZM Logo (colour).jpg', class: "Logo") %>
```

you are applying the class `"Logo"` to the `img` tag.

The subtle difference is the the position of the closing round bracket. Take a look in your stylesheet and see if you are trying to apply the `"Logo"` class to the `a` tag or the `img` tag.

Now if you look at the big picture, you are trying to put a link inside of a link.

The following:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <%= link_to image_tag('ZM Logo (colour).jpg'), class: "Logo" %> 
</a>
```

will produce:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <a class="Logo"><img source='ZM Logo (colour).jpg'></a>    
</a>
```

When what you actually want is:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <%= image_tag 'ZM Logo (colour).jpg', class: "Logo" %> 
</a>
```

which will produce:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <img source='ZM Logo (colour).jpg', class='Logo'>
</a>
```

Be careful with your use of Rails functions and when in doubt, right click on the element in the web browser and click `Inspect element`. This way you can see the HTML output.